# source command doesn/t work when used inside shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I am using an installer which is adding an environment variable in the `~/.bash_profile` file.

When I'm starting the jetty server, it is unable to find that entry...

When I run

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

it reloads the `~/.bash profile` file and server starts successfully without any issues.

The problem is that my customer is not going to start a new shell session, nor will he manually refresh the `~/.bash_profile` file.

I tried to add the `source ~/.bash_profile` command inside a shell script that I call when I invoke the startup script of the jetty server, but it doesn't work either.

Is there any other way we can reload `~/.bash_profile` of the current session? Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of this shell script. Indicate the line that's giving you trouble. Include any error messages that you get.

Comment: Is Jetty running under its own account? Does it have a matching profile in its home?

Answer (score 1):

A shell script is typically not run by bash (except when you explicitly arrange this).

Note that on many Linux system /bin/sh now is `dash` and since `source` is a non-standard shell command that was imported from `csh`, a shell like dash does not support it.

The POSIX defined dot command (`.`) should work as long as the file parameter you pass it contains no non-standard extensions.